# Junit Test keeps Failing and importing data for another class issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, junit4

Hi I just finished a 3 week crash course on Java, Selenium, Junit. So im still trying to wrap my head around everything. I created a test class to run through Junit some simple tests between 2 classes. But I keep getting errors from Junit and wanted to reach out the community for help. This is my class with the data:
`

```
package pages;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class bobprofile {


WebDriver driver;
    public bobprofile(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
    }


    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='ja-container-fl']/div/div/div[1]/table[6]/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]")
    public WebElement runs;
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='ja-container-fl']/div/div/div[1]/table[6]/tbody/tr[6]/td[5]")
    public  WebElement balls;
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='ja-container-fl']/div/div/div[1]/table[7]/tbody/tr[6]/td[8]")
    public WebElement wickets;
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='ja-container-fl']/div/div/div[1]/table[7]/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]")
    public  WebElement overs;


public void batting(){

    System.out.println("Did bob score more than 200 runs?");


    int myruns = Integer.parseInt(runs.getText()); 
    int myballs = Integer.parseInt(balls.getText());
    if(myruns<200){
        System.out.println("No he Didnt");


    } else {
        System.out.println("Yes he did");
    }
    System.out.println("He scored " +myruns+ " Runs of " + myballs +" Balls");

}


public void bowling(){
System.out.println("Did bob take any wickets this year?");


int mywickets = Integer.parseInt(wickets.getText());
int myovers = Integer.parseInt(overs.getText().substring(0, 2));
if(mywickets<=0){
    System.out.println("No he Didnt");


} else {
    System.out.println("Yes he did");
}
System.out.println("He got " +mywickets+ " wickets of " + myovers +" Overs");

    }
}
`
```

This is my class with the Junit test:

```
    package pages;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class TestingLogic {






    @Test
    public static void bobShouldHaveAtLeast150Balls(){
        bobprofile myprofile = new bobprofile();
        int MyBallCount = Integer.parseInt(myprofile.balls.getText());
        assert(MyBallCount > 150);
        /*if(MyBallCount>150){
            return "yes";
        } else return false; */
    }

    @Test
    public static void bobShouldHaveAtLeast4Overs(){
        int MyOverCount = Integer.parseInt(bobprofile.overs.getText());
        assert(MyOverCount > 4);
    }


}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.Exception: Method bobShouldHaveAtLeast150Balls() should not be static
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoid(FrameworkMethod.java:93)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:155)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateTestMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:208)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:188)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

java.lang.Exception: Method bobShouldHaveAtLeast4Overs() should not be static
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoid(FrameworkMethod.java:93)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:155)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateTestMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:208)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:188)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: You keep getting errors from JUnit. If anyone is to help, please quote error messages and stack trace exactly in your question (you may edit it to include the information).

Comment: Post the url which you are testing and the errors which you get. Btw, where did you get this tutorial ? Some tutorials are pretty horrible, btw.

Comment: The url is: http://accleague.org/index.php?option=com_omrcricsys&view=stats&layout=player_detail&vd=1&ua=59&ld=2345&Itemid=94

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: the methods should not be static. Remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: JUnits recognizes only "public void" methods as @Test methods.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the JUnit 4 documentation, in [FAQ section](http://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#atests_1), there is a nice basic example of what the syntax for a JUnit test should look like.

And, indeed, @paul-hicks and @rafał-laskowski are correct with their comments.